# calculate age in xslt from birthday

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, date, web-parts, dataview

I have a variable caled `Birthday` which will have value like `1/1/1970`. I need to calculate the age of a person based on that value. It would basically be the year from `currentdate()-year` from the `Birthday` variable. But How do I achieve this in XSLT? It is related to sharepoint DateView webpart. There is a field `Birthday` of `datetime` type. I need to extract age using that field. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 1.0 since it is SharePoint, unfortunately

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the source XML document? Please, provide. It isn't clear what your definition of "age" is -- years, or years-months, or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite resource for anything XSLT is [Dave Pawson's website](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/).  One section deals with [date manipulations in XSLT 2.0](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/dates.html#d14942e139), and it seems to have very clear answers about how to do this.

Basically, you have to make sure that the date is in the correct format, then just use date subtraction:

```
xs:dateTime(actual-arrival) - xs:dateTime(xs:date(due-date))
```

(Note: I have not tested this.)

The XSLT 1 faqs are [at this link](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/dates.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is somewhat complex in XSLT 1.0, if you are more easy going with javascript you could do something like this:

```
<div id="mydate"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[

      function datejs(datexslt) {
        var date = datexslt.split('T')[0].split('-');
        var time = datexslt.split('T')[1].split(':');
        return new Date(date[1] + '/' + date[2] + '/' + date[0] + ' ' + time[0] + ':' + time[1] + ':' + time[2].substr(0, 2) + ' UTC'); 
      }

      var utc = datejs(']]><xsl:value-of select="@PublishedDate" /><![CDATA[');

      //$('#mydate').text(utc);

]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="Age">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="month-from-date(current-date()) > month-from-date($Birthday) or month-from-date(current-date()) = month-from-date($Birthday) and day-from-date(current-date()) >= day-from-date($Birthday)">
            <xsl:value-of select="year-from-date(current-date()) - year-from-date($Birthday)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="year-from-date(current-date()) - year-from-date($Birthday) - 1" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```